# how to select complete Column when a cell in that column is selected?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, gridview

Currently, I am working on Gridview of ASP.net VS2010. In this application
1. I want to select complete column on a selection of 1 single cell in that column. 
2. Gridview have 2 groups into it. Each group having same column name.
Like

__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*_

Unloading       | Loading
***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__**

Amount| Item | Amount| Item
      |      |       |

If I select Loading-> Amount column, it should select Unloading->Amount and Loading->Amount column as well.

Your any kind of guidance will help.

Thanks,
TA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to do it by JQuery.
Code snippet is as below.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {
        var rows = $('#grd tr');
        rows.children().click(function () {
            rows.children().removeClass('Highlighted');
            var index = $(this).prevAll().length;  
     rows.find(':nth-child(' + (index + 1) + ')').addClass('Highlighted');  });
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com) to accomplish this. Give "ColumnA" a special class and "ColumnB" a special class. When "ColumnA" is clicked, all "ColumnB" cells will be highlighted:

```
//Wait for the document to load.
$(document).ready(function()
{
    //Add a handler for when anything with class "ColumnA" is clicked.
    $(".ColumnA").click(function()
    {
        //When that happens, add the "Highlighted" class to all elements with the class "ColumnB."
        $(".ColumnB").addClass("Highlighted");
    });
});
```

Should get you on the right path.

Comment: Can we do it in JavaScript and C# as I don't know jQuery?

Comment: Follow the link to jQuery and you will find it is a JavaScript library. You can certainly do it without and that would mean manually looping through each cell you want to highlight. With jQuery it is a simple JS script that you include and then use something like the script I posted. I recommend you take a look and give it a try - it will make many things much easier.

Comment: Hi Josh, able to do it through JQuery